# .htaccess mod rewrite, condition issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For url like: http://sub.domain.com rule from third line should apply. It worked before but on new server it doesn't.

Rules from last two lines for url like: http://sub.domain.com/test works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*\..*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ site/index.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ site/index.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ site/index.php?site=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ site/index.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```